# Observing memory leak in CachingSessionFactory ( DefaultSftpSessionFactory)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp, spring-integration-amqp

We have build spring microservice which uses spring integration framework with Rabbit mq as messaging system. Our application establish the sftp session with SFTP server and poll the files every 3 seconds. In a day we get around 5oo files and we are using `CacheSessionFactory` and `DefaultSessionFactory` with spring integration version 5.2.3. However, we observed three 3 different issues :

1. Over the period of time , in production we observed that there is memory leak. There are lots of `SftpSession` objects are remining in memory.
2. Intermittently we are getting error as "Failed to obtain Pooled item".
3. One or 2 time, we observed the Poller thread is getting stuck and had to restart the system.

[Number of SFTP session objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF9GP.png)

[Dominator Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV7ct.png)

[CacheSessionFactory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVZdB.png)

We have this simple instantiation of DefaultSessionFactory and CacheSessionFactory.

---

DefaultSftpSessionFactory sessionFactory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();

```
    sessionFactory.setHost(sftpHost);
    sessionFactory.setPort(sftpPort);


    sessionFactory.setUser(sftpUser);
    sessionFactory.setPassword(sftpPassword);
    sessionFactory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    return sessionFactory;
```

}

---

public CachingSessionFactory cachingSessionFactory(DefaultSftpSessionFactory defaultSftpSessionFactory) {
CachingSessionFactory csf = new CachingSessionFactory(defaultSftpSessionFactory);
return csf;
}

---

Comment: We tried setting CacheSessionFactory with 300 size but there is no luck. Intermittently poller thread was getting stuck

Comment: Hi @Sushil, I'm facing the exactly same problem, any solution?